# Computer freezes when handling some source files

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I'm having rather weird issues where downloading/saving/editing source files sometimes causes my computer to freeze.

First time I encountered the issue was when trying to download a .c file from my university. The computer immediately froze and although the file was created and contained data, it was all corrupt (i.e. none of the code got saved). The same thing happened again whenever I tried it. The computer also froze when I tried to save the file using Notepad++ after copypasting it from the browser, but oddly enough everything went smooth when I tried copypasting into Geany and saving from there instead.

Today, I encountered the issue again, but this time when trying to create an empty Matlab file using the "edit file.m" command. The file was created, but my computer froze (I had to restart using the power button).

The question is, how should I start debugging? I have no idea what actually causes these problems, nor how to find any logs/other things that might be helpful. I'm thinking it might have something to do with my antivirus (Avast Free Antivirus, up to date), but I'm not sure. I'm on W7 64bit.

Edit: After some testing, CryptoPrevent turned out to be the culprit. Either disabling or updating it was enough to make the problems go away.

Comment: Have you checked the event log for disk errors? That's the first thing I'd look at with those symptoms. Then I'd run memory tests.

Comment: Couldn't find any relevant errors in the event log (other than the computer having been turned off incorrectly, as it was the only way to turn it off). It could be worth mentioning that I've used this computer for almost five years, and never had any similar issues before.

Comment: It's good that you've been happy with computer (until now) for five years, but computers do develop problems over time. Use memtest86. Try running with subsets of your RAM. etc. Another possibility is that you need a new power supply.